# how do I count multiple columns in the same table?

Tags: sql

```
DimpersonID DimnetworkID DimsocialID
--------------------------------------
 -1          -1           8
-1          -1            -1
-1          -1            -1
-1          -1            -1
2           -1            3
-1          4             -1
```

I have a table like this, and I want to know how many -1 in DimpersonID, DimnetworkID, and DimsocialID. I want a result turn like this below.

```
            DimpersonID DimnetworkID DimsocialID
Total Count      5       5             4
```

I assume I need to run select count(*), but I am not good at SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when DimpersonID = -1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when DimnetworkID = -1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when DimsocialID = -1 then 1 else 0 end)
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, If I have ten tables need so the same thing, count '-1' under different columns. Is that a way I can combine everything. I can list all of them like this.        
                      DimpersonID DimnetworkID DimsocialID
Total Count      5       5             4

Comment: @Jason . . . This question is about a single table with three columns.  If you have a question about ten tables, you should ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and database tag.

Comment: Sure, too new for this website.